# SortedSet not working as per documentation

Tags: java, sortedset

I have two sample code below. please review them and help me to spot the mistake

```
SortedSet<String> names = new TreeSet<>();
names.add("ar");
names.add("aj");
names.add("ka");
names.add("ru");
names.add("ti");

System.out.println(names);
SortedSet<String> rangeView;
rangeView = names.subSet("ar", "ti");
System.out.println("flag is "+names.remove("ti"));
System.out.println(rangeView);
System.out.println(names);
```

The output here is perfectly fine. names.remove("ti"); return true and range view also includes the fromElement and excludes toElement

But if I store an Employee object in the sorted set the **remove** does not removes the element and also range view shows that fromElement is excluded and toElement is included

here is the code snippet

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee("aj", LocalDate.parse("2019-09-20"), "57764");
Employee emp2 = new Employee("ar", LocalDate.parse("2016-06-20"), "5324");
Employee emp3 = new Employee("ka", LocalDate.parse("2017-07-21"), "2809");
Employee emp4 = new Employee("ru", LocalDate.parse("2018-08-12"), "2765");
Employee emp5 = new Employee("ti", LocalDate.parse("2018-08-12"), "2762");

SortedSet<Employee> names = new TreeSet<>();
names.add(emp1);
names.add(emp2);
names.add(emp3);
names.add(emp4);
names.add(emp5);
System.out.println(names);
SortedSet<Employee> rangeView;
rangeView = names.subSet(emp3, emp1);
System.out.println("flag is "+names.remove(emp5));
System.out.println(rangeView);
System.out.println(names);
```

Employee class has name, date of hiring and emp id as fields. it implements Comparable interface and compareTo method compares on hireday and equals case is handled.

**the compareTo method is pasted below:**

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee second) {
    int compareFlag = this.getHireday().compareTo(second.getHireday());
    if(compareFlag!=0){
        return compareFlag;
    }
    return this.getEmpid().equals(second.getEmpid()) ? 1:-1;
}
```

The problem I am facing is:

1. the remove method does not actually removes the object from names
2. subSet excludes fromElement and includes toElement

Comment: Does your `Employee` implement `equals` and `hashCode` correctly?

Comment: No i have not implemented these two. but how will ot affect the subSet and remove method

Comment: Are you still getting the employees from aj to ti? If so, ti is before aj by hireday - I haven't checked the TreeMap source code but that may explain issue 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `compareTo` method violates the general contract of a `Comparable`. Consider `emp1` and `emp2` in your example. `emp1.compareTo(emp2)` will return `-1`, but `emp2.compareTo(emp1)` will also return `-1`.

You can fix this by comparing the ids instead of just checking they are equal, which should make your set work as expected:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee second) {
    int compareFlag = this.getHireday().compareTo(second.getHireday());
    if (compareFlag != 0) {
        return compareFlag;
    }
    return this.getEmpid().compareTo(second.getEmpid()); // Here
}
```

Comment: I suggest to mention `equals` method should be consistent to `compareTo` also for `SortedSet` to work.

Comment: @Mureinik thank you quick reply. I spent 2 hours to spot the mistake. I would have never solved this thing... to be frank i did not even know that i had violated the contract. I thought implementing compareTo will suffice

Comment: @tin_tin, no. There should be all three: `equals`, `hashCode`, `compareTo`.